# GAE Boilerplate how to add a terms and privacy page

Tags: google-app-engine, boilerplate

I am trying to add a terms of use and privacy page to the google app engine boilerplate.

I can't figure out how to add a link on the footer to a new page; where I can paste in the terms and privacy text.

I tried to make a download link to a privacy.txt file (placed txt file on boilerplate/static/img) and couldn't get that to work either, I think I needed to add the link to the routes.py file but as someone new I can't get it to work. Any help with this would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your app yaml. There you find the answer why your .txt file will not be served from the static/img folder.

With a small change it can be served from your static folder:

```
- url: /(privacy\.txt|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|crossdomain\.xml)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(privacy\.txt|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|crossdomain\.xml)
```

Or create your own static folder for serving txt files. See the img example in your app.yaml

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to get that to work my link in base.html looks like             {% block footer %}
            <footer>
            
              <a href="http://www.mywebsite.appspot.com/static/Privacy.txt" target="_blank">Terms of use and Privacy</a> 
            
            </footer>
            {% endblock %}

Comment: and I put that code in app.yaml and I put a file called privacy.txt in the static folder of gae boilerplate, the static/img of gaeboilerplate, the static of the boilerplate folder, and the static/img of the boilerplate folder. Could it be that I have multiple copies of the same file across all the files? If this is hard to diagnose could you maybe explain how I would make a new page and a link to it so I could just paste the privacy text there? Thanks in advance I really appreciate your help.